# Constructor in Strict Mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, constructor, strict

I've been searching a lot for an answer to this REALLY simple question, but I cannot find it:

" How to create constructors in strict mode ? "

```
fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${country_name}`, )
.then(response => {

    if(! response.ok)
        throw new MyError(response.statusText, response.status)
```

[...]

```
.catch(err => {
    renderNotFound(err.message, err.code)
```

[...]

```
class MyError {
constructor(message, code) {
    this.message = message
    this.code = code
}}
```

I know the `.this` keyword resolves to `undefined` in strict node. So how can we work around it to create constructors?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: fixed a missing `}` in the class MyError

Comment: It only resolves to `undefined` in normal function calls. Calling a method or constructor fills in `this`.

Comment: thanks. why doesn't this code work, then? It works if I don't use strict mode

Comment: @VitorHugo - That code should work just fine assuming you have a closing `}` on your `class`.

Comment: Yeah, I do x) It wasn't copied, but I'll edit it

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Are you sure the `.then()` function is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create constructors in strict mode?

When using `class` syntax, constructor functions are always in strict mode, because the body of a `class` is always strict. (Most new kinds of scope defined in ES2015+ are strict by default.)

> I know the .this keyword resolves to undefined in strict node. So how can we work around it to create constructors?

No workaround required. `this` is set to `undefined` when you call a function without doing anything to set `this` (for example: `example()`). When you use `new`, `this` is set to an instance of the thing being created before your constructor code is called (in a base constructor) or when you call `super(/*...*/)` (in a subclass constructor). (And when you do something else to set `this` (like `example.method()` or `method.call(example)`), `this` is set just like it is in loose mode.) Example:

```js
class MyError {
    constructor(message, code) {
        this.message = message
        this.code = code
    }
}

const x = new MyError("Ooops!", 42);
console.log(x.message); // Ooops!
console.log(x.code);    // 42
```

---

Just to underscore the point that `class` bodies are in strict mode by default:

```js
class MyError {
    // Code here is strict, even though the script
    // context around it isn't
    static example() {
        console.log(this === undefined);
    }
}

const loose = {
    // Code here is loose like the script context around it
    example() {
        console.log(this === undefined);
    }
};

let f;

f = MyError.example;
f(); // true

f = loose.example;
f(); // false
```

---

In a comment you've suggested that code doesn't work in strict mode. It should, assuming you have a `}` on your `class`. It does in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/zs9xowrk/) (can't do `fetch` in stack snippets, sadly):

```
    "use strict";

    class MyError {
        constructor(message, code) {
            this.message = message
            this.code = code
        }
    }

    fetch(`/this-will-404`, )
    .then(response => {
        if(! response.ok)
            throw new MyError(response.statusText, response.status)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        renderNotFound(err.message, err.code);
    });

    function renderNotFound(message, code) {
        console.log(`Not found: ${message} ${code}`);
    }
```